# Count number of times that columns A & B contain values that also appear in column B & A

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database, I have a table with those values :

```
column_a,column_b
1,2
3,4
2,1
4,3
3,1
5,6
1,4
1,3
```

I'm able to know how many times there's a match between a specific value, and any other value. Take value "1" :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column_a` = 1) as T1
JOIN (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column_b` = 1) as T2
WHERE T1.`column_b` = T2.`column_a`
```

Resultat will be 2, because we have `1,2`, `2,1`, `1,3` and `3,1` -> 1 matches with 2 and 3.

Now, I want to know the total number of matches. Here, it will be 3 (because there's `3,4` and `4,3`).

Does anyone have and idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to count all the cases where a matching pair is found but restricting the matches such that only the pair where `column_a`is greater than `column_b` is selected to avoid duplication:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `table` t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM `table` t2
  WHERE t2.column_b = t1.column_a AND t2.column_a = t1.column_b
    AND t2.column_a < t1.column_a
)
```

Output:

```
3
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51654f/3)

Comment: Wow, this is very handy! Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select count(distinct case when a = 1 then b else a end)
from t
where 1 in (a, b);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=5fcc8db541b4ce18f1b1d6fa1b88760f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I don't understand well what your query does... Does it only retrieve matches for value "1" ? Thank you

Comment: @Y-BCause . . . It counts the distinct values of the non-1 `a`/`b` value.

Comment: It counts the number of non-"1" values in a/b.  I can't think of a simpler method and this is likely to be among the best performing as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `least()` & `greatest()` function :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM `table` t1
      GROUP BY LEAST(column_a, column_B), GREATEST(column_a, column_B)
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) t;
```

Here is a [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51654f/14).